# Can I run Meteor from two paths?

Tags: meteor

How do I clone and run auth branch with my app, installed at [SRH/meteor/myapp], in addition to having master meteor installed in [usr/local/meteor]?

After having cloned the auth branch, when I attempt to add a package to my app (via meteor add accounts-ui), an error states the package is not available. Clearly, it is looking for the package at: [usr/local/meteor], while I am attempting to run meteor from [SRH/meteor].

Is it OK to have meteor installed at two locations?  Obviously, I am confused.

More specifically, how do I clone the auth branch directly to [usr/local] location? Note: I am a newbie to git cloning.  Took me a long time to find a tip on how to clone a branch, using:
git clone -b auth git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things.

1. Clone the auth branch to a location (as you have described) and then run meteor via

   ```
   ../../path/to/cloned/auth/branch/meteor run
   ```
2. Use [meteorite](http://possibilities.github.com/meteorite/) which was basically created to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I found some ways to accomplish, including physical copy/paste of the desired packages from the download location to the /usr/local/meteor path. Some of my confusion stems from other issues (it appears). Meteorite looks interesting, however. I am going to check it out.

Comment: I still have a question whether you can run meteor from multiple locations (paths), one at a time... and add packages to an app from that particular meteor path. It seems calling: meteor add package is ALWAYS looking for that package within the '/usr/local/meteor' path.

Comment: Yeah, but if you run `path/to/meteor add package` it will look at the packages installed in that particular meteor installation. However, meteorite makes all this a lot easier for you..